# How to identify verified Facebook Pages via the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook recently introduced verified pages (see https://www.facebook.com/help/196050490547892). Here's an example https://www.facebook.com/SpiderManDVD

I'd like to create a directory of verified movie pages but can not find a way to identify verified pages through the API. Does anyone know if this is possible at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `is_verified` in FQL page table

For example,

`SELECT is_verified FROM page WHERE username='FakeSupport' or username='Facebook'`