# FQL user table: is_verified vs verified

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I assume one of these is the celebrity kind of verified and the other refers to whether a user has clicked an activation link, but can't find any official documentation aside from the following:

```
is_verified
bool    
Whether the user is verified

verified
bool    
Indicates whether or not Facebook has verified the user
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210382/how-to-identify-verified-facebook-pages-via-the-api) is_verified is the celebrity kind (though the answer doesn't sound super confident about that), but if that's the case I can't find anything about `verified` ... e.g. if this field is false should I assume the user is more likely to be a spammer and ask to confirm their email address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`verified` tells if the user did one of three things in Facebook:

1. verified a credit card
2. verified the user phone number by SMS
3. registers for mobile

Here is the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

See that not necessarily [the email has been verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280535/is-it-possible-to-check-if-an-email-is-confirmed-on-facebook/19417686)

Comment: Thank you! Very informative. Sorry for the late acceptance, I had kinda given up on this.

Answer (score 0):

The verification just assures that it's the official page of the celebrity. If it's not verified that doesn't mean it's a spam, just that it's created by fans.

Comment: Right, I assume that's what one of these fields is for, but surely both ambiguous (is_)verified fields aren't used for the same thing. Not being a celebrity, I can see if I query my own account `verified` comes back true. So now my question is, under what conditions is the `verified` field false?

Answer (score 0):

*is_verified* means they are a specific person in real life (maybe a celebrity would get this status?) while *verified* means they had their account verified by phone or credit card (which only means they are probably a physical person and not a bot with a fake profile, but they could still be lying about themselves in their profile).

To elaborate on the documentation link as indicated by @neves...

**verified**: FB has manually verified the authenticity of their identity manually.

**is_verified**: user taken any of these steps:

- Register for mobile
- Confirm their account via SMS
- Enter a valid credit card